# Connect OpenAM with multiple LDAP servers

Tags: ldap, openam

I have installed OpenAM in my ubuntu machine and installed LDAP.

I could able to authenticate with the Datastore (default : embedded) credentials, but couldn't able to connect with LDAP server.

My issues are -

When I add authentication chains with multiple(3) LDAP servers and Datastore which is default to 'Top Level Realm', I need to submit the form 4 (3 LDAP+ 1 Datastore) times to autheticate (I have added Datastore as 4th and first 3 were my LDAP servers).

Even I have tried multiple(3) possible configurations (uid, cn) for same LDAP server, nothing authenticating from the external LDAP.

Added another realm and tried passing arguments (REALM=newName) to use the new realm and it still authenticating from 'Top Level Realm'.

I am using dc=nodomain(verified) and cn=admin with admin password to bind user. OpenAm is accessing through http://localhost:8080/openam and LDAP through PhpLDAPAdmin installed at http://localhost:50389.

Please help!

Comment: `Instance1 - DataStore
Criteria - SUFFICIENT
Options - iplanet-am-auth-shared-state-enabled=true`

`Instance2 - LDAP
Criteria - REQUIRED
Options - iplanet-am-auth-shared-state-enabled=true iplanet-am-auth-shared-state-behavior-pattern=useFirstPass`
Configured the options in chanin as above, which doesn't resolved the issue.